# Stop background from repeating after a specific point

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to stop a background image from repeating after a specific(though dynamic) point?

Currently I have the following html

```
<ul>
  <li>variable</li>
  <li>amount</li>
  <li>of</li>
  <li>items</li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```
ul {
  background-image: url('./imgs/gridlines.png');
  background-repeat: y-repeat;
}
```

Now, the above repeats the image for the entire length of the `ul` element. My issue is I need the repeating to stop 8px from the bottom of the `ul`.

I've tried using `background-position` but this just shifts the background, while still repeating it to the end of the `ul` element.

I've also tried using `background-size: 1 calc(100% - 8px);` but this fails for chrome.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SReject/nqrpp61t/)

Comment: Would `margin-bottom: 8px;` solve your problem?

Comment: No, as I need the repeating background to stop roughly 1/2 way down the last `li` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in CSS...sort of. You cannot tell `background-repeat` to repeat a specified number of times; it doesn't work that way. So my idea is to stick an 8px white block at the bottom of the list, which should accomplish something very close to the desired effect:

```css
ul {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/B5k8FTP.png');
  background-repeat: y-repeat;
    padding-left:0;
    color:black;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
}
li:last-child{
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}


ul::after{
    display:block;
    background-color:white;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    height:8px;
    width:100%;
    content:"";
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>variable</li>
  <li>amount</li>
  <li>of</li>
  <li>items</li>
</ul>
```

The `ul` style sets a width for the sake of the demo. `padding-left:0` removes the margin from the left side of the `<ul>`, also optional. The position is set to be relative, because `after` content will be positioned absolutely, relative to the `<ul>`/

The `ul::after` style inserts the white block after the list. `position:absolute` and `bottom:0px` place it at the bottom of the list, relative to the `<ul>`. The `z-index` is set to ensure it sits behind the bottom `<li>`

The `li:last-child` makes sure that it sits on top of the `ul::after` content.

Comment: For my usage the `li:last-child` stuff isn't needed. anyways, thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the content you want inside a frame that is set to inherit the size from parent - the 8 px you want.

If I am misunderstanding something a jsfiddle would be nice.

EDIT:
[Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/nqrpp61t/6/)

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    height: 46px;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/qIaw9Lc.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: fiddle added to the OP